# Laravel валидация поля email в экшне

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется форма:

```
<form method="post" action="/my/settings/change/email" class="password__cog-entry">
    <div class="password__cog-entry-item">
        <label>Введите новый email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email">
    </div>
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="password__cog-entry-button">
        <button type="submit">Изменить email</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Как в контроллере провести валидацию?

Comment: версия laravel какая?

Comment: Последняя версия

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу выше, мы можете сгенерировать свой собственный валидатор http запросов:

```
php artisan make:request EmailFormPostRequest
```

описать в нем правила валидации:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ];
}
```

и добавить класс валидатора параметром в тот метод, который обрабатывает action формы:

```
public function store(EmailFormPostRequest $request)
{
    // Форма заполнена правильно, делайте с email то, что планировали. 
}
```

Остальное Laravel сделает за вас. Подробнее можно посмотреть в документации с примерами: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation

Answer (score 0):

Например так

```
public function someMethodPOST(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ]);

    ...
}
```